# Uiautomator "am start"

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

Does any body know how to call
`am start -a ACTIVITY` from `uiautomator` code.
Or is it possible to start activity right from `junit` code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example I use to start an activity from the .jar file:

```
private boolean startSettings() {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings");
        sleep(1000);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        sleep(1000);
        if (getUiDevice().getCurrentPackageName().contains(
                "com.android.settings")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can modify the code to start any app. You could also make the method more generic by adding a parameter for the package/ activity value.

Comment: I have tried am start -n `com.app.myapp/.MainActivity`
Not working. Fully qualified name too not working. 

but from command prompt `adb shell am start -n com.app.myapp/.MainActivity` is working

any ideas?

Comment: I have no idea why this is happening. I defined a method for starting an app and I used the code above with no issues.
You could try using the python version of uiautomator:https://github.com/xiaocong/uiautomator
I've been using it for a while and it works great. You could then use the python subprocess.Popen() to run the "adb shell am start"  command.

Answer (score 5):

It shoule be of with the following code. I use this in my test.

```
UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
final String TARGET_PACKAGE =
        InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getPackageName();

Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
final Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(TARGET_PACKAGE);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
device.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(TARGET_PACKAGE).depth(0)), 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have done, is make the starting the app and running your UIAutomator tests part of the build. This is how I get my UIAutomator test to run after I build the Ant build.xml. This snippet is added to the end of the build.xml and causes your application to start, then starts your UI tests. Using eclipse make sure you go to right-click build.xml then -> Run As -> Ant Build... and make sure the correct targets are selected: 'build', 'install', 'start', 'mytest'. Targets 'start' and 'mytest' are added by following snippet.

```
<!-- version-tag: VERSION_TAG -->
<!-- This line should already be at the end of build.xml -->
<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/uibuild.xml" />

<target name="start" description="Start App" depends="build, install">
    <echo>Starting Navigation Example</echo>

    <exec executable="${adb}" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="shell" />
        <arg value="am" />
        <arg value="start" />
        <arg value="-n" />
        <arg value="com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample/.MainActivity" />
    </exec>
</target>

<target name="mytest" description="Runs UI tests" depends="build, install, start">
    <echo>Running UI Tests</echo>
    <exec executable="${adb}" failonerror="true">
       <arg value="shell" />
       <arg value="uiautomator" />
       <arg value="runtest" />
       <arg value="${out.filename}" />
       <arg value="-c" />
       <arg value="com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainTestCase" />
   </exec>
</target>
```