# How to broadcast an intent from UIautomator

Tags: android, android-intent, android-uiautomator

I just want broadcast an intent using UI automator.

This question is something related to 
[Uiautomator "am start"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941372/uiautomator-am-start)

But i am able to start intent using "am start -n Intent" but unable to start a broadcast intent using UIautomator like "am broadcast -a Intent"

Answer (score 1):

From your test you can use

```
InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(...));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Context.sendBroadcast(..)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)) to broadcast an Intent.